# Subsection is not working well in my thesis template. Also when I load the {arabtex} package things are missed up

Tags: arabtex

I am writing my thesis using this template. I have two problems:
First: the subsection and subsubsection commands are not working.
Second: I need to use the {arabtex} package. however when I load this package things are missed up.

her is my template:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,times]{memoir}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm, paperwidth=210mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{arabtex}
%\usepackage{utf8}
\makeatletter
  \newcommand\mySixteen{\@setfontsize\mySixteen{16pt}{16pt}}
  \newcommand\myEighteen{\@setfontsize\myEighteen{18pt}{18pt}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
% To change the label of references to 1. instead of [1]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\mainmatter
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{12pc}
% to add text to the top of each page of list of figures
\newif\ifendLOF
\newcommand*{\lofheader}{\vspace{0.5cm}%
\ifendLOF\else\hbox to \linewidth%
  {{~\ul{\textbf{Figure}}}~\hfill{\ul{\textbf{Description}}}~\hfill{\ul{\textbf{Page}}}}\par%
  \vspace{12pt}%
  \afterpage{\lofheader}
\fi}%
% to add text to the top of each page of list of tables
\newif\ifendLOT
\newcommand*{\lotheader}{ \vspace{0.5cm}%
\ifendLOT\else\hbox to \linewidth%
  {{~\ul{\textbf{Table}}}~\hfill{\ul{\textbf{Description}}}~\hfill{\ul{\textbf{Page}}}}\par%
  \vspace{12pt}%
  \afterpage{\lotheader}
\fi}%
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{\mySixteen Chapter\space}% p. 151, memmanual
\renewcommand*{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
\cftchaptername\protect\NumToName{#1}\space--\space}% p. 152, memmanual
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\large\mdseries}
%\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{2.25em \@plus\p@}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesectionskip}{1sp}
\newgeometry{top=23mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\printlottitle}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries ABSTRACT}
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}
{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries ACKNOWLEDGMENT}\abstract}
{\endabstract}
\newenvironment{dedication}
{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\centering\mySixteen\bfseries DEDICATION}\abstract}
{\endabstract}
% Abstract: Remove indents around abstract text
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
% Change font size to conform with the rest of the document text
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\textbf
  {\figurename~\thefigure}}
  \renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\textbf
  {\tablename~\thetable}}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt} % Vertical space above & below [h] floats
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt} % Vertical space below (above) [t] ([b]) floats
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
\DoubleSpacing
\chapterstyle{brotherton}
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\mySixteen\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\mySixteen\bfseries}
\setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{:~}
\setaftersecskip{1sp}
\setbeforesecskip{1sp}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{27pt}
%\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{1sp}
%\setlength{\afterchapskip}{-10pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1sp}
\renewcommand\bibname{\mySixteen\bfseries References}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{myEighteen}
\textbf{My Title}
\end{myEighteen}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\DoubleSpacing
\newgeometry{top=48mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm}
\DoubleSpacing
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{mySixteen}
\textbf{My Title} \vspace{\stretch{1}}
\end{mySixteen}
\begin{large}
By \\
\textbf{Me } \\
Advisor\\
\textbf{My Advisor} \\
Co-Advisor \\
\textbf{my Co-advisor
%\footnote{EECS at Case Western Reserve University, Clevelan, OH, USA}
}
 \vspace{\stretch{1}}
 Thesis Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the Degree of
M.Sc. in Computer Engineering\\At \\Faculty of Graduate Studies
\\my schol\\
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\vspace{3cm}
January, 2017
\end{large}
%\vspace{\stretch{0.5}}
\end{center}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\phantomsection \label{dedication}
\SingleSpacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries DEDICATION}
\DoubleSpacing
\begin{dedication}
\begin{center}
\emph{To My Lovely Father and Mother: Anwar and Manal} \\
\end{center}
\end{dedication} 
\newpage
\SingleSpacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
\DoubleSpacing
\begin{acknowledgments}
My sensate thanks go to my advisor.
\end{acknowledgments}
\newpage
\SingleSpacing
\newgeometry{top=31mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm}
\SingleSpacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries TABLE OF CONTENT}
\tableofcontents*
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures*
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofheader}
\endLOFtrue
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables*
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lotheader}
\endLOTtrue
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\large\mdseries ABSTRACT}
\newgeometry{top=48mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm}
\begin{abstract}
\begin{center}
\begin{mySixteen}
\textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} \\
\vspace{1 cm}
\end{mySixteen}
\begin{large}
By\\
\textbf{TTTTTTTT}\\
\end{large}
\end{center}
\vspace{1 cm}
%{\setlength{\baselineskip}
%{1\baselineskip}
%\emph{
Various techniques....
\end{abstract}
%\doublespacing
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\newgeometry{top=23mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm}
\DoubleSpacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
The mental disorders such
\chapter{Literature Reviews}
\label{Literature Reviews}
\section{Introduction}
IoT systems are

\subsection{IoT systems for Healthcare}
this is a subsection
%\begin{singlespace}
\SingleSpacing
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip}
\newpage
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{30pt}
\bibliography{Thesis}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\mySixteen\bfseries Abstract in Arabic Language}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume what you mean by `subsection` is not working is that it is not being numbered? This is the default behaviour of the `memoir` class.

To enable numbering of `subsection` use

```
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
```

To enable this numbering to appear in the table of contents use

```
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

As for `\usepackage{arabtex}`, I am unsure what you mean by 'things are messed up'?

Comment: Many thanks for your help with the subsection.

Comment: what I meany with "things are missed up" is that when I load the {arabtex} package, I start getting many errors. You can try it in the above example.